How to Resolve and Exit a Git Merge Conflict in PythonAnywhere Bash
I'm currently working on resolving a Git merge conflict in the bash console on PythonAnywhere. After running the git merge command, I'm presented with a screen that shows a merge commit message file. However, I'm having trouble interacting with this file—I can't edit it, and I'm unable to exit the screen.
Screenshot:
Merge Commit Message Screen on PythonAnywhere
I'm new to using Linux systems and Vim (or whatever editor this is), and I'm feeling stuck. I've tried pressing various keys on my keyboard to get out of this mode, but nothing seems to work. I've searched online for solutions but haven't had any luck.
Could someone please guide me on how to properly handle this situation? How can I exit this screen after editing (or not editing) the merge commit message? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Looks like you might be in a [tag:vim] editor window, google vim. Meanwhile, try :q or <escape button>:q to exit. I've no idea what "pythonanywhere" is but FWIW in a normal shell you'd set and export the variables EDITOR, VISUAL, and/or FCEDIT to whatever editor you like before using any tool that's going to throw you into an editor window. I hear nano or pico are editors that people new to Unix and used to Windows editors like to use, at least until they get used to vim or emacs other common Unix editors.
